# Nexus 5 charging problem

Tags: root-access, charging

My Nexus 5 recently has a charging problem.. If I wiggle the charger a little it sometimes give the notification that the charger is not connected and if I release the charger it says its charging, I guess that problem is because my nexus 5 charger input is broken ??

And if I charge it while the screen is on ( and using the phone ) the phone takes a long time to charge and if I leave it with sometimes the screen of ( and not using the phone ) it charges 0 to 100 real quick.

If somebody know what I can do, I would be very thankfull

Phone information:
-Rooted Nexus 5
-Version 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

It just sounds like the plug is a little loose in the socket. This can often happen with cheaper USB cables. Just try a different USB cable and you'll probably get a snugger fit.

It's entirely normal that the phone charges more quickly when you're not using it. When you're using it, you're draining the battery at the same time as trying to charge it. It's like trying to fill a bath while the plug's out.

> If somebody know what I can do, I would be very thankful

You don't need to do anything. Your phone is working correctly.